# Can I use @else/@elseif within @unless in Laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade

I just found out about using `@unless` instead of `if(!...)` so I changed some of my clauses.
But I just realized that I had an if-else-statement, so I only changed it from this:

```
@if (!empty($data['note']))
  <p>{{ $data['note'] }}</p>
@else
  <p>no information given</p>
@endif
```

to this:

```
@unless (empty($data['note']))
  <p>{{ $data['note'] }}</p>
@else
  <p>no information given</p>
@endunless
```

But it didn't change anything and seems working correctly.

**Is it okay/normal to use `@else`and `@elseif` within @unless-statement?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sure is okay. `Unless` is just an inverse of `if`, instead of using `!` in the condition itself. So you can then chain as many `else` as you would with an `if` statement.